# После обновления Gradle не видит новую версию

Tags: gradle

Здравствуйте. Столкнулась сегодня со следующей проблемой. При попытке сборки проекта Gradle выдал следующую ошибку:

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin']. This version of Shadow supports Gradle 3.0+ only. Please upgrade.

Я честно полезла смотреть, как у меня версия Gradle. После набора команды

```
gradle --version
```

увидела, что у меня версия 2.10.

Вот отсюда https://gradle.org/install/ была скачана новая версия и установлена. Все инструкции с сайта были выполнены. Однако, когда я снова набрала

```
gradle --version
```

то увидела, что версия Gradle по-прежнему 2.10.

Если честно, я не понимаю, почему так происходит и как это исправить. Буду благодарна за помощь.

Comment: Какие нибудь переменные окружения не изменились? Вы старую версию деинсталлировали?

Comment: Старую версию я просто удалила. По сути установила gradle заново, самую новую версию. В переменную PATH все прописала.